# How to reference media files by using string array in android?

Tags: arrays, android-activity, reference

In my android program, I have a string array containing words, Eg:

```
string arr[]={"asong", "bsong", "csong"};
```

I have media files with the same name in my res/raw folder. The array size is actually very large(50-60 elements). So I want to play the raw files using

```
R.raw.(arr[1])
```

or something like that which may equal R.raw.bsong, is there a way to do something like this? Or do I have to reference each one separately as is the tradition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string arr[]={"asong", "bsong", "csong"};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
int song= getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + arr[i], null,
        getPackageName());

InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(song);

// play the song logic here

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted. Btw, how do I play the song logic using above code? Should I just give use this reference as ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id of all the raw resources

```
int idOfSong1 = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + arr[1], "raw",
            getPackageName());
int idOfSong2 = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + arr[2], "raw",
            getPackageName());
int idOfSong3 = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + arr[3], "raw",
            getPackageName());
```

And get the data of the raw files as

```
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(idOfSong1);
```

Comment: See that's the thing. There are 50-100 resource files. It would be a tedious job to use this approach(even if i just copy and paste and then edit the names.)